# Задачи по JavaScript не пойму деталей языка

Tags: javascript

1. В задаче нужно вывести простые числа от 1 до 10.
   Почему не срабатывает строка с `if`?
   Интересует именно строка, решение на том  сайте есть:

   ```
   for (var n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
     if (n % (n - 1) == 0) {
       continue;
     }
     alert(n);
   }
   ```
2. Почему не срабатывает функция без нижнего кода с `if?
   Хотел чтобы после ввода возраста запускалась функция, а она не срабатывает, если нету нижнего кода:

   ```
   function checkAge(age) {
     if (age > 18) {
       return true;
     } else {
       return confirm('Родители разрешили?');
     }
   }
   var age = prompt('Ваш возраст?');

   /**if (checkAge(age)) {
     alert( 'Доступ разрешен' );
   } else {
     alert( 'В доступе отказано' );
   }**/
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ```
   for (var n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
           if (n==2) {
              console.log(n);
           }
           if(n==3) console.log(n);
           if(n==1) continue;
           if(n%2!==0 && n%3!==0) console.log(n);
   }
   ```
2. Потому что сверху ты объявил функцию, а снизу ты ее вызываешь.
   Просто объявленная функция ничего не вернет, если ее не использовать.

Comment: Насчет 1 там по итогу в alert должно попасть 2,3,5,7 типа простые числа и пропустить остальные.
Насчет 2 я понял) спасибо

Comment: Исправил, но что-то с форматированием

Comment: Вы видели сколько я сделал отступов для того, чтобы вывод был красивым? Запомните это и используйте потом.

Comment: @Other, благодарю